# installing node,inputting npm-v,There is an error,The error displays as following

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

$ npm -v
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_globa                   l'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-ha                   ndler.js:213:17)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:83:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:215:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:253:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach ()
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:                   25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:                   178:20)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:                   53
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:213
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\                   error-handler.js:213:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:373:26)
5.3.0

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and provide a [mvce] by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/100

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache and reinstall npm:

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g npm@latest
```